# How to know, whether leaflet layer is fully rendered or not in browser?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to check the layer rendering event. I have tried the following code, but it is not working. Am I missing something?

```js
var renderer = new L.canvas(); // I tried with L.svg() too
var latlngs = [[37, -109.05], [41, -109.03], [41, -102.05], [37, -102.04]];
var polygon = L.polygon(latlngs, { color: 'red', renderer: renderer }).addTo(map);

//update event
renderer.on('update', () => {
      console.log('polygon loaded')
      renderer.off('update')
    })
```

I notice that the update method on the renderer only works after a map pan or zoom event. But on the first map render, it didn't trigger. Any help, please?

> I have added the same question in `leaflet` [discussion section](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/discussions/8981)

PS: The following code works perfectly for the `tilelayer` but not on the other type of layers.

```js
tile_layer.on("load",function() { console.log("all visible tiles have been loaded") });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change the order of your code.Specially these lines.

```
renderer.on('update', () => {
    console.log('polygon loaded')
    renderer.off('update')
})
var polygon = L.polygon(latlngs, { color: 'red', renderer: renderer }).addTo(map);
```